# XSD Unique constraint (XML Schema)

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, unique

I'm having a little trouble with the Unique constraint with an XML schema.

Here is a portion of the XML to be validated:

```
    <pieces>
    <whitePieces>
    <pawn   name="p" taken="false" POSonBoard="12"></pawn>
    <pawn   name="p" taken="false" POSonBoard="12"></pawn>
    <rook   name="r" taken="false" POSonBoard="11"></rook>
    <rook   name="r" taken="false" POSonBoard="81"></rook>
    <knight name="n" taken="false" POSonBoard="21"></knight>
    <knight name="n" taken="false" POSonBoard="71"></knight>
    <bishop name="b" taken="false" POSonBoard="31"></bishop>
    <bishop name="b" taken="false" POSonBoard="61"></bishop>
    <queen  name="q" taken="false" POSonBoard="41"></queen>
    <king   name="k" taken="false" POSonBoard="51"></king>
  </whitePieces>
  <blackPieces
(and you get what goes here I'm sure)
```

(notice how the two pawns at the top have the same POSonBoard value)

And here is a portion of the XSD (or should I just post the whole thing? It's quite lengthy)

```
<xs:element name="blackPieces">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

              <xs:element name="pawn" minOccurs="8" maxOccurs="8">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="P"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute ref="POSonBoard"></xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="rook" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="10">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="R"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute ref="POSonBoard"></xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="knight" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="10">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="N"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute ref="POSonBoard"></xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="bishop" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="10">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="B"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute ref="POSonBoard"></xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="queen" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="9">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="Q"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute ref="POSonBoard"></xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="king" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="K"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute ref="POSonBoard"></xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="testUnique">
      <xs:selector xpath="POSonBoard"/>
      <xs:field xpath="pieces"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
```

I'm not even 100% sure i put the unique constraint in the correct place
(assume that root elements and what have you exist but were not included above to save some space, everything is well formed [except the unique constraint perhaps])

If anyone could steer me in the right direction, that would be fantastic!
(also if there's anything else you notice that isn't very well done, please do tell)

Answer (score 1):

I had to fiddle about with the source to get it to work. Note that I've cut down your original code a fair amount for brevity.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<pieces xmlns="http://www.example.org/pieces" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/pieces XMLSchema1.xsd">
  <whitePieces>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p1"></pawn>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p2"></pawn>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p2"></pawn>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p2"></pawn>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p2"></pawn>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p2"></pawn>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p2"></pawn>
    <pawn name="P" taken="false" POSonBoard="p2"></pawn>
  </whitePieces>
</pieces>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/pieces" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/pieces" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="pieces">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="whitePieces">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="pawn" minOccurs="8" maxOccurs="8">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="P"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
                  <xs:attribute name="POSonBoard" type="xs:string" />
               </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          <xs:unique name="testUnique">
            <xs:selector xpath="tns:pawn" />
            <xs:field xpath="@POSonBoard" />
          </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The interesting part is the XPath value on the selector:

```
<xs:selector xpath="tns:pawn" />
```

And that the XPath value for the field has been adjusted to look at the attribute:

```
<xs:field xpath="@POSonBoard" />
```

It looks as though the namespace was the issue. I hope that helps.

Comment: Alas, I still could not get said code to validate correctly. I appreciate the help, but to my knowledge, my code looks quite very similar to yours and still it doesn't work.
(also i would like the attribute "POSonBoard" to validate globally not just for the pawn piece, but i guess, to run we should first learn to crawl)

Comment: Perhaps you could post your full code? Also, if you are open to changing the format of your POSonBoard attribute slightly, have you considered changing the type to xs:ID? You could make the format something like p[1-32] - this would be globally unique.